# How to deny deleting folders in share

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, share

Sometimes, users move folders from share. They're need "write" access to write file to share. How to prevent folder lossing?

Comment: Denying "delete" permission is silly if the users have "write" permission.

Answer (score 1):

On the ntfs you can grant write permissions, and deny delete folders, delete files.

You can also set this for the folder, folder and files, subfolders and files.

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Read [this page](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Ownership_and_Permissions), I guess it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I've seen (bottom of [this thread](http://forum.gon.com/showthread.php?t=618712)):

> DENY the "Delete Subfolder & Files",
>   "Delete", and "Create Folders / Append
>   Data" and Apply to "This Folder and
>   subfolders" to the usergroup. Then do
>   another [advanced permissions entry] for that user group and
>   set everything to allow except full
>   control, change permission and take
>   ownership and apply it to "This
>   folder, subfolder, and files."
>
> That effectively prevents a user from
>   creating/deleting folders but they can
>   do whatever they want with files.